# Why was 6 afraid of 7?

Tags: code-golf, string

### *Why was 6 afraid of 7? Because 7 8 9!*

Given a string apply the following transformations:

- If there is a 6 next to a 7 remove the 6 (6 is afraid of 7)
- If the sequence "789" appears remove the 8 and the 9 (7 ate 9)

(If I'm not mistaken it doesn't matter what order you do the transformations in)

Keep applying these transformations until you can no longer.

Example:

`78966`

First we see "789", so the string becomes "766". Then we see "76", so we take out the 6, and the string becomes "76". Then we see "76" again, so we are left with "7".

Test Cases:

- `987` => `987` (Not in the right order. Does nothing.)
- `6 7` => `6 7` (The whitespace acts as a buffer between 6 and 7. Nothing happens)
- `676` => `7`
- `7896789` => `77`
- `7689` => `7`
- `abcd` => `abcd`

Comment: Why was Vista afraid of 7? Because 7 8 10.

Comment: Another test case `68978966897896` => `68977`

Comment: @ThomasKwa Oh, I get it: Microsoft skipped Windows 9 because they were going along with the riddle. ;)

Comment: Why afraid of seven was five? Because six seven eight. [--Yoda](http://favoritememes.com/_nw/15/50320933.jpg)

Comment: I could be wrong but I'm sure this is an example of a Lindenmayer system.

Comment: @Pharap Link, please.

Comment: @geokavel Facinating stuff. Here's three as a start: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system#Examples_of_L-systems) [2](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~joel/PaperFoldingFractal/L-system-rules.html) [3](http://www.cgjennings.ca/toybox/lsystems/)

Comment: @Pharap Thanks for the links! I guess the difference is mine always makes the string smaller, so maybe it's an inverse L-System?

Comment: @geokavel `Alphabet: 6789; Axiom: 78966; Rules: 67 -> 7, 789 -> 7;` Not sure if that's entirely correct but you can see how it would be mapped to an L-system.

Comment: @Pharap Nice. Also, `76 -> 7`.

Comment: @geokavel That too. If I knew of a language centred around L-Systems I'd submit an answer but I don't believe that there is one.

Comment: Six was afraid seven because seven had cold, dead eyes.

Comment: Because of the "_Keep applying these transformations until you can no longer._", it would be good to add some test cases reflecting that.. Like `68978966897896` that @BradGilbertb2gills suggested almost 3 years ago, or `7689689` → `7`.

Comment: Windows 9 doesn't exist - **BECAUSE WINDOWS 7 8 IT**

Comment: Why was Windows Vista afraid of 7? Because 7 8 9!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 12

Translation of the sed answer:

```
6*7(6|89)*
7
```

[Try it online](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=Nio3KDZ8ODkpKgo3&input=OTg3CjYgNwo2NzYKNzg5Njc4OQo3Njg5CmFiY2QKNjg5Nzg5NjY4OTc4OTYKNjc3ODk)

Comment: Works in [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS) too!

Answer (score 12):

## Java, <s>126</s> <s>81</s> <s>66</s> 58 bytes

Thanks to @GamrCorps for providing the lambda version of this code!

Thanks to @user902383 for pointing out an autoboxing trick!

...yup.

It's actually longer than I expected - Java replaces items in strings with `replaceAll()` once per match, not repeatedly until it stops changing. So I had to use a fancy for loop.

#### Lambda form:

```
x->{for(;x!=(x=x.replaceAll("67|76|789","7")););return x;}
```

#### Function form:

```
String s(String x){for(;x!=(x=x.replaceAll("67|76|789","7")););return x;}
```

#### Testable Ungolfed Code:

```
class B{
    public static void main(String[]a){
        System.out.print(new B().s(a[0]));
    }
    String s(String x){for(;x!=(x=x.replaceAll("67|76|789","7")););return x;}
}
```

Comment: Why not go with a lambda? Will save at least 15 bytes

Comment: @GamrCorps Don't know how to phrase that - never use functions.

Comment: what's the point of interface and not class?

Comment: @eis Interface removes the need to declare main as public, which gives the slightest advantage. See: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64713/44713

Comment: Lambda version: `x->{for(;!x.equals((x=x.replaceAll("67|76|789","7"))););return x;}`

Comment: Forgot to add the new byte count (66)

Comment: @user902383 The reduction you're making is by changing `.equals` to `!=`, which does _not_ do the same thing. `==` (or `!=`) compares by object hex location, not by value. It's the same length otherwise. `while()` is 7 bytes, `for(;;)` is 7 bytes.

Comment: @FlagAsSpam i know, but seems it works when i test it

Comment: @user902383 Huh. Must be an autoboxing thing I never saw before. I'll test it here as well.

Comment: other thing is in your equal statement you have double bracket. `equals(( statement ))`

Comment: @user902383 Yes, that was for the reassignment of x, but I forgot that single-functions statements don't need the extra brackets.

Answer (score 12):

## Javascript ES6, 29 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/6*7(89|6)*/g,7)
```

Test:

```
f=s=>s.replace(/6*7(89|6)*/g,7)
;`987 -> 987
6 7 -> 6 7
676 -> 7
7896789 -> 77
7689 -> 7
abcd -> abcd`
.split`\n`.every(t=>(t=t.split` -> `)&&f(t[0])==t[1])
```

Comment: Great, and since 9 is eaten, you only have 2 bytes and win with this answer :P

Answer (score 9):

## GNU Sed, 17

Score includes +1 for `-r` option.

```
s/6*7(6|89)*/7/g
```

Comment: Doesn't work for `67789` should return `77` but it instead returns `677`

Comment: You can use  `s/67|7(6|89)/7/` instead of `s/6?7(6|89)/7/`

Comment: Gee, I wonder where Larry came up with the idea of `s///g`?

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>19</s>  18 bytes

```perl6
{S:g/6*7[6|89]*/7/} # 19 bytes
```

```perl6
$ perl6 -pe 's:g/6*7[6|89]*/7/' # 17 + 1 = 18 bytes
```

( Note that `[6|89]` is the non-capturing version of `(6|89)` which is spelt as `(?:6|89)` in Perl 5. `<[6|89]>` is how you would write what's spelt as `[6|89]` in Perl 5)

usage:

```perl6
$ perl6 -pe 's:g/6*7[6|89]*/7/' <<< '
987
6 7
6676689
7896789
7689
abcd
68978966897896
79|689
'
```

```
987
6 7
7
77
7
abcd
68977
79|689
```

Comment: I don't know Perl 6, but I assume this is a repeated substitution. If the `6*` and the `[6|89]*` don't match anything, what stops the `7` being substituted for `7` ad infinitum?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma It swaps `7` with `7` then starts again at the next position, working its way until the end. `:g` is short for `:global` not `repeat until it doesn't match anymore`.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma To get `s/67|76|789/7/` to work on `667` I would have to write it as something to the effect of: `while s/67|76|789/7/ {}` which of course would never stop if you wrote it as `while s/6*7[6|89]*/7/ {}` as you would expect. Also, the end of the previous comment may come off as mean spirited, that is [not](https://github.com/perl6/specs/blob/9fc6bb74cf103627f619505cd4eea856f65d5766/S27-perl-culture-draft.pod6 "S27") how it was inteded

Comment: Cool - thanks for the explanation!  No mean-spiritedness was given or taken :)  My motivation is purely curiosity which your explanation has satisfied - thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the `[]` be changed to `()`?  You don't want to match pipes or `79999`.

Comment: @jwodder No `[]` is the Perl 6 non-capturing version of `()`, what you are thinking of is spelled as `<[6|89]>` in Perl 6.

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth, 17 bytes

```
u:G"67|76|789"\7z
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%3AG%2267%7C76%7C789%22%5C7z&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=987%0A6+7%0A676%0A7896789%0A7689%0Aabcd)

Leaky Nun has outgolfed this by a byte in the comments.

Comment: http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3Az%226%2a7%286%7C89%29%2a%22%5C7&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=987%0A6+7%0A676%0A7896789%0A7689%0Aabcd&debug=0

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](http://perl.org), 17 bytes

```sh
perl -pe 's/6*7(6|89)*/7/g' # 16 + 1
```

usage:

```sh
$ perl -pe 's/6*7(6|89)*/7/g' <<< '
987
6 7
6676689
7896789
7689
abcd
68978966897896
'
```

```sh
987
6 7
7
77
7
abcd
68977
```

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 52 bytes

```
StringReplace[#,"67"|"76"|"789"->"7"]&~FixedPoint~#&
```

Explanation:

```
                                                   &   A function returning
                                     &                   a function returning
              #                                            its first argument
StringReplace[ ,                    ]                     with
                "67"                                        "67"
                    |                                      or
                     "76"                                   "76"
                         |                                 or
                          "789"                             "789"
                               ->                         replaced with
                                 "7"                       "7"
                                    ~FixedPoint~        applied to
                                                #        its first argument
                                                        until it no longer changes.
```

Comment: The golfed code is clearer than the explanation code.. :)

Comment: @Rob Haven't made many explanations before, going for a systematic approach.

Comment: I was just teasing, mate :)

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 27 bytes

This solution is from comments, credit to *Brad Gilbert b2gills*.

```
->s{s.gsub /6*7(6|89)*/,?7}
```

---

### Ruby, 37 bytes

***(old solution)***

This solution uses the fact that you will never need to replace more times than characters in the string.

```
->s{s.chars{s.sub! /67|76|789/,?7};s}
```

Comment: You can use `chars` instead of `size.times` to save a few bytes.

Comment: Doesn't Ruby have the global flag for regex substitution, or would that take more bytes to enable?

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills, in Ruby is like in Awk: there are separate `sub()` and `gsub()` methods to replace first or all. So global is just one character longer.

Comment: @manatwork Then I would write this something like: `->s{s.gsub /6*7(6|89)*/,'7'}`, and let `gsub` do all the looping work.

Comment: If I understand the rules of command line flags correctly, you could save 16 bytes by using the -p command line flag (+1) making it `gsub /6*7(6|89)*/,?7` with usage `ruby -pe "gsub /6*7(6|89)*/,?7"` for a total of 20+1 bytes

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 17 bytes

```
jt"'789|76'55cYX]
```

#### Example

```
>> matl
 > jt"'789|76'55cYX]
 > 
> 7896789
77
```

**EDIT**: [**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=anQiJzc4OXw3Nic1NWNZWF0&input=Nzg5Njc4OQ)

#### Explanation

```
j                   % input string
t                   % duplicate
"                   % for each character. Iterates as many times as the string length
    '789|76'        % regular expression for replacement
    55c             % string to insert instead: character '7'
    YX              % regexprep
]                   % end for
```

This works by applying a regular expresion replacement for *as many times as there are characters in the original string*. This is enough, since each substitution reduces the number of characters.

Answer (score 3):

### Rust, 96 bytes

```rust
fn f(mut s:String)->String{for _ in 0..s.len(){for r in&["67","76","789"]{s=s.replace(r,"7")}}s}
```

Hopelessly long, as per usual for Rust...

Ungolfed:

```rust
fn seven_ate_nine(mut str: String) -> String {
    for _ in 0..str.len() {
        for to_replace in &["67","76","789"] {
            str = str.replace(to_replace, "7");
        }
    }
    s
}
```

Comment: At least it's not Java

Answer (score 3):

## Emacs Lisp, 59 bytes

```
(lambda(s)(replace-regexp-in-string"6*7\\(6\\|89\\)*""7"s))
```

It becomes a bit clearer with spaces:

```
(lambda (s) (replace-regexp-in-string "6*7\\(6\\|89\\)*" "7" s))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), 15 bytes

```
Ur"6*7(89|6)*"7
```

Simple RegEx solution

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VXIiNio3KDg5fDYpKiI3&input=Ijc4OTY3ODki)

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 27 bytes

```
$args-replace'6*7(89|6)*',7

e.g.
PS C:\temp> .\ate.ps1 "7689"
7

PS C:\temp> .\ate.ps1 "abcd"
abcd

PS C:\temp> .\ate.ps1 "68978966897896"
68977
```

Making use of:

- someone else's regex pattern
- the way `-replace` does a global replace by default in PowerShell
- loop unrolling, where it will apply the `-regex` operator to the array `$args` by applying it to all the elements individually, and there's only one element here because there's only one script parameter, so it works OK and we can avoid having to index element `[0]`.

---

Novelty previous attempt before realising a global replace would do it; 74 bytes of building a chain of "-replace -replace -replace" using string multiplication, as many times as the length of the string, then eval()ing it:

```
"'$($args)'"+("{0}6|6(?=7)'{0}89'"-f"-replace'(?<=7)")*$args[0].Length|iex
```

(With a bit of string substitution to shorten the number of replaces).

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously, 29 bytes

```
,;l`'7;;"67"(Æ"76"(Æ"789"(Æ`n
```

Takes input as a double-quoted string, like `"6789"`. [Try it online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=2c3b6c6027373b3b22363722289222373622289222373839222892606e&input=6789) (you will need to manually quote the input).

Explanation:

```
,;l`'7;;"67"(Æ"76"(Æ"789"(Æ`n
,;l                            get input and push its length (we'll call it n)
   `                       `n  call the following function n times:
    '7;;"67"(Æ                   replace all occurrences of "67" with "7"
              "76"(Æ             replace all occurrences of "76" with "7"
                    "789"(Æ      replace all occurrences of "789" with "7"
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 36 bytes

```
preg_replace('/6*7(6|89)*/','7',$a);
```

regex solution, takes $a string and replaces via the expression.

Comment: [GET parameters are not acceptable as an input method in PHP](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7591/45941). You will need to either make this a function and pass the input as function parameters, or get input from `$argv` or STDIN.

Comment: @Mego There appears to be no consensus on the post you linked to.

Comment: @immibis Correct. A consensus is required to make an I/O method acceptable. The lack of one means it is not acceptable.

Comment: TL;DR you have serious disadvantages if you use PHP for codegolf.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_%28programming_language%29), 26 bytes

```
67::=7
76::=7
789::=7
::=
```

including a trailing newline.

Input is appended to the program before starting it.
Output is read off the program state when it terminates, similarly to a Turing machine.
(Thue *does* have an output stream, but it's difficult to use correctly, so I'm not sure whether this is an acceptable output method)

Comment: I don't think so. If you have a way to STDOUT, you have to. Sorry!

Comment: Yes, this is allowed according to the meta post.

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, <s>70</s> 64 bytes

Thanks to @Peter Taylor for cutting `{"789":I}{"76:":I}?` to `"789""76"?:I`

`"67":Iq:A{AI#:B){AB<7+A{BI,+}~>+s:A];}{"76"I={"789":I}{"76":I}?];}?}/A`

`"67":Iq:A{AI#:B){AB<7+A{BI,+}~>+s:A];}{"76"I="789""76"?:I];}?}/A`

I know this could probably be golfed a lot further and your help would be greatly appreciated, but frankly I'm just happy I managed to get the answer. This was my first attempt at writing CJam.

Explanation:

```
"67":I                e# Assign the value of 67 to I
q:A                   e# Read the input and assign to A
{                     e# Opening brackets for loop
    AI#:B)            e# Get the index of I inside A and assign to B. The increment value by 1 to use for if condition (do not want to process if the index was -1)
    {                 e# Open brackets for true result of if statement
        AB<           e# Slice A to get everything before index B
        7+            e# Append 7 to slice
        A{BI,+}~>     e# Slice A to get everything after index B plus the length of string I (this will remove I entirely)
        +s:A          e# Append both slices, convert to string, and assign back to A
        ];            e# Clear the stack
    }                 e# Closing brackets for the if condition
    {                 e# Open brackets for false result of if statement
        "76"I=        e# Check if I is equal to 76
        "789"         e# If I is 76, make I 789
        "76"?:I       e# If I is not 76, make I 76
        ];            e# Clear the stack if I does not exist inside A
    }?                e# Closing brackets for false result of if statement
}/                    e# Loop
A                     e# Output A
```

Comment: I haven't attempted this question myself, so I'm not sure whether this is the best approach, but if you want to do splitting and joining then take a look at `/` and `*`. Also note that thinking in terms of stacks when you're used to C-like languages takes some adaptation. E.g. `{"789":I}{"76":I}?` can pull out the assignment to become `"789""76"?:I`, which can be further golfed to ``78976`3/?:I``.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't quite understand how to use your second suggestion however.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. ``78976`3/`` gives an array `["789" "76"]`; then rather than using `?` you would need to use `=` to index; but it's back-to-front, so it would need the index to be inverted, losing the advantage.

Answer (score 1):

### R, 35 bytes

```
cat(gsub("6*7(6|89)*",7,scan(,"")))
```

I didn't know I could use `gsub` this way, a big thank you for every answer here that made me learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](https://dyalog.com), 17 bytes

```
'6*7(6|89)*'⎕R'7'
```

`'6*` any number of sixes
`7` followed by a seven
`(`…`)*'` followed by zero or more sequences of…
 `6|89` a six or eight-nine

`⎕R` **R**eplace that with

`'7'` a seven

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki///), 19 bytes

```
/67/7//76/7//789/7/
```

You can't actually provide input in this language, so the supposed input goes to the right of the code, which is allowed by recent rules.

Comment: Note that [Itflabtijtslwi](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Itflabtijtslwi) is slashes but with input.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Although that one inputs *characters*, not *strings*.

Comment: Your link seems to be missing one slash.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 46 bytes

```py
import re
lambda s:re.sub(r'6*7(6|89)*','7',s)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf/), 15 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=cGkiNio3KDZ8ODkpKiI3) Do I really have to explain?

```
pi"6*7(6|89)*"7
p               replace any entity in
 i               the input
  "6*7(6|89)*"   that matches this regex
              7  with 7
                implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

### **PHP 51 characters**

```
while($s!=$r=str_replace([789,67,76],7,$s)){$s=$r;}
```

**Test case written in long hand**

```
$s = '78966';
while ($s != $r = str_replace([789, 67, 76], 7, $s) )
{
    $s = $r;
}
echo $s; // 7;
```

This does the string comparison and the string replace both in the while condition. If while condition is met, it updates the left hand of the comparison with the result. Let me know of any improvements.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 71 bytes

Clojure is less-than-ideal for golfing due to its verbose nature - but nonetheless it's an interesting exercise:

Golfed version, using Java interop:

```
(defn f[s](let[x(.replaceAll s "67|76|789" "7")](if(= s x)s(recur x))))
```

Un-golfed version, using Java interop:

```
(defn six-fears-seven [s]
  (let [x (.replaceAll s "67|76|789" "7")]
    (if (= s x)
      s
      (recur x))))
```

Un-golfed "pure Clojure" version:

```
(defn six-fears-seven [s]
  (let [x (clojure.string/replace s #"67|76|789" "7")]
    (if (= s x)
      s
      (recur x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, <strike>102</strike> <strike>82</strike> 67 (+7)? bytes

#### extglob version

```bash
x=$1
while v=${x/@(76|67|789)/7};[ $v != $x ];do x=$v;done
echo $v
```

This is meant to be put in a file and called with e.g. `bash -O extglob 789.sh 6567678989689789656`. The (+7)? bytes is for if the extglob option counts toward bytes.

Thanks to @BinaryZebra for pointing out extglob features!

---

#### Non-extglob version (82 bytes)

```bash
x=$1
while v=${x/76/7};v=${v/67/7};v=${v/789/7};[ $v != $x ];do x=$v;done
echo $v
```

This is meant to be put in a file and called with e.g. `./789.sh 65678989656`.

It makes use of parameter expansion to search and replace in a loop. I involved a series of expansions to do the replacing since I'm not aware of a way to more effectively chain expansions.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @BinaryZebra Ah, thanks for the `@()` syntax. I knew there had to be a way to combine those. And @Mego, thanks for the welcome!

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 12 bytes

```
e/6?7(6|89/7
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ZS82PzcoNnw4OS83&input=LW1SIFsKIjc4OTY2IiwKIjk4NyIsCiI2IDciLAoiNjc2IiwKIjc4OTY3ODkiLAoiNzY4OSIsCiJhYmNkIiwKIjY4OTc4OTY2ODk3ODk2Igpd)

#### How it works

`String.e` is recursive replace function. Japt 2 has a new regex syntax and auto-completion of parentheses inside regex, which saves one byte here. (In Japt 1.x, we had to pass strings in place of regexes, which was kinda clunky.)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Δ67Â‚789ª7:
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3BQz88NNjxpmmVtYHlplbvX/P5BhBkYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVulir6TwqG2SgpL9/3NTzMwPNz1qmGVuYXlolbnV/1qd/5YW5lxmCkBsbsYFFDYDYi5zMyCRmJScwmUI5BqbmxlBpMyBisyA2BzMBSMuIAZxoBQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Δ            # Continue doing the following until it no longer changes:
 67          #  Push 67 to the stack
   Â         #  Bifurcate (short for Duplicate & Reverse copy): 76
    ‚        #  Pair them together: [67,76]
     789ª    #  Append 789 to this list: [67,76,789]
         7:  #  Replace all occurrences of these three integers with 7
             #   i.e. 1789372 → 17372
             # (after the loop, output the result after implicitly)
```

`67Â‚789ª` could alternatively be `•4BĆx•₄в` for the same byte-count.

Answer (score 0):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 27 bytes

```
{x{"7"/y@x}/(\'$67 76 789)}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxFkVFrwyAQx9/9FIcUlsISBwNtEzb2sOc+7a0r1CYaQzvN1JKE0n32qU03UP78f96d3inLy3jBDJPpbbyS7PNhQRkwCmy1Xl4R8uVlsZ1+bCkBYKz25lhle8m7UzVWU2WXuyvy23AEeL1iuJp1d4ehToJR/yGjEcIjvkEc7qJhJ4jZXyRmdIb3yAj5oW4CvOkOIYKU970rCalNI1pzkoXzvD6KsVZct6KozRf5PgvnO6MdoZQ+PZNBTfnAXU5zLi3vmtzInCGE4vtCA/DymiTbGA+dBq8E2K5VHoxthC3g3QgH2njV6bZYprTQYkyLkn2E+EF1Xrie1wJ47R3wsOBwllJYOAg/CKFDMNcNsAI2t1KgeN8L7eaK4RtCRZbMPKMEZkJnm1wcR3RREfoFlgR8jQ==)

- `$67 76 789` shorthand for `("67";"76";"789")`
- `(\'...)` create list of splitter functions, i.e. `("67"\;"76"\";"789"\)`
- `x{...}/(...)` set up a reduce, seeded with `x` (the input), run over the list of splitter functions

  - `{"7"/y@x}` split the input (`x`) using the current splitter function (`y`), then join the result with `"7"`. feed this to the next iteration of the reduce